# ¿Cómo deserializar una cadena JSON Array a un objeto en C# desde Odata?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Alguien puede ayudarme a deserializar el siguiente JSON. El JSON es devuelto por un servicio OData (Funciona con la librería restsharp 106.31) y devuelve la siguiente cadena en "response.Content".

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "BlaBla",
                    "type": "TipoBlabla"
                },
                "CDESCRIUATION9AB26271537FD8FE": "Americas",
                "CIDCONTIDROOT2C0191C14B785F9A": "TEST 1",
                "CPRICESUATION503363A1609841F3": "SMI00001",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E46": "1000",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_01": "108",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_02": "1300",
                "KCAMOUNTUATION5766473FFF195FF7": "660.000000"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "BlaBla",
                    "type": "TipoBlabla"
                },
                "CDESCRIUATION9AB26271537FD8FE": "Americas",
                "CIDCONTIDROOT2C0191C14B785F9A": "TEST 1",
                "CPRICESUATION503363A1609841F3": "V0000177",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E46": "1000",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_01": "108",
                "CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_02": "1300",
                "KCAMOUNTUATION5766473FFF195FF7": "1000.000000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Luego al tratar deserializar en .net tengo problemas:

```
             var client = new RestClient("URL");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic USRPASX64");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", "CookieCustum");
        var body = @"";
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

        string jsonString = response.Content;


        List<sBDResults> TsBDResults = new List<sBDResults>();
        TsBDResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sBDResults>>(jsonString);
        //sBDResults results =   JsonSerializer.Deserialize<sBDResults>(jsonString);

        Console.WriteLine($"CDESCRIUATION9AB26271537FD8FE: {TsBDResults}");
```

La línea "TsBDResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(jsonString)" arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.
Saludos

Comment: el problema es que no te llega una lista te llega un objeto que tiene la propiedad "d" y dentro tiene la propiedad "results" y este results es probablemente la lista que estas esperando

Comment: Me queda la duda si las propiedades de este tipo `CDESCRIUATION9AB26271537FD8FE ` siempre tienen el mismo nombre o van variando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, ten una clase de ese json:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class D
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
    public string CDESCRIUATION9AB26271537FD8FE { get; set; }
    public string CIDCONTIDROOT2C0191C14B785F9A { get; set; }
    public string CPRICESUATION503363A1609841F3 { get; set; }
    public string CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E46 { get; set; }
    public string CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_01 { get; set; }
    public string CPRICESUATION7F0B8C544CD86E4_02 { get; set; }
    public string KCAMOUNTUATION5766473FFF195FF7 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public D d { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora puedes deserializar:

```
var resultados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Herramienta usada para pasar json a clase de C#:

https://json2csharp.com/

También puedes hacer "pegado especial" de Json a clase en el Visual Studio.

Comment: Pero que buena herramienta!!! me vino como anillo al dedo

Comment: @Yussef esta es mas completa, te genera mejor el código https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: @Daniel Muchas gracias estimado, voy a probarla también. (Y yo como un burro haciéndolo manualmente ...)

Comment: hey @Yussef hermano, no te hables así, tienes mucho talento y muchas habilidades, que desconozcas algunas cosas no te hace un "burro". :D

Comment: Gracias fredy, me hiciste sonrojar!